# IEnumerable.Any

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method which returns jobs for a certain date range and status. The problem is that when I'm using IEnumerable.Any, it returns all jobs even those that do not have the specified status. Is there a way to fine-tune it so that it only returns jobs with a particular status? Here's the code:

```
public List<JobDTO> GetJobList(int domainID, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo, PlannedTravelStopStatusTypeEnum status)
{
    var context = new WebSchedulerContext();
    var list = new List<JobDTO>();

    if (dateFrom == null)
    {
        dateFrom = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    if (dateTo == null)
    {
        dateTo = DateTime.MaxValue;
    }

    var jobs = context.Job.Include(j => j.PlannedJobStopDetails
          .Select(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop)
        )
        .Where(j => j.MinimumStartDate >= dateFrom && j.MaximumEndDate <= dateTo &&
               **j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any**(
                 jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status
                 ));

    foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        list.Add(new JobDTO(job));
    }

    return list;
}
```

The code fragment in question is :

```
j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any(jsd => 
    jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what's in your tables, what you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: IEnumerable.Any doesn't return elements of a sequence but just true or false if one of your elements in the sequence matches the condition. So it is possibile that your conditions is always true

Comment: Do all "PlannedJobStopDetails" must have this particular status? If yes then you should use All instead of Any.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman When I use All it returns zero results but an equivalent SQL query ran agaisnt the database returns 3 results.

Comment: How is `PlannedJobStopDetails` linked to `Job`? Is it 1:many?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Yes its 1:many

Comment: So the `GetJobList` method does not return correct results?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is a 1 : n relation between a `Job` and `PlannedJobStopDetails`.

And in your statement you say: Give me a job, if **any** of its `PlannedJobStopDetails` (this is a collection) has the "status" to look for.
Perhaps you want to say that each of the `PlannedJobStopDetails` should have the same status?

Then you need to change from "Any" to "All":

```
    var jobs = context.Job.Include(j => j.PlannedJobStopDetails
  .Select(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop)
)
.Where(j => j.MinimumStartDate >= dateFrom && j.MaximumEndDate <= dateTo &&
       j.PlannedJobStopDetails.**All**(
         jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status
         ));
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do; that each of the PlannedJobStopDetails should have the same status in thr returned Job

Comment: Then just change from calling "Any" to "All".

Answer (score 0):

`j.PlannedJobStopDetails.Any(jsd => jsd.PlannedTravelStop.PlannedTravelStopStatus == status)` returns **true** if any of the `PlannedJobStopDetails` have a `PlannedTravelStopStatus` matching `status`.

If you want to only return the jobs where all of the `PlannedTravelStopStatus` match your given status, use `All()`.

**Edit**: On second thought, are you sure that `PlannedJobStopDetails` is actually a foreign key relationship that EF understands?